# Understanding shared_ptr thread safety

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

I understand that `shared_ptr` offers some thread safety. The guarantee seems to be that if multiple `shared_ptr` instances are destroyed at the same time, the object is destroyed only once. The case seems to be that nothing else about the smart pointer is thread safe, i.e., copying, moving, etc. And that makes sense as that would be difficult to achieve without explicit use of mutexes. Having said that, would an implementation like this be thread-safe in the way the standard decrees?

```
#include <atomic>
#include <utility>

template<class T> struct SharedPtr {
private:
  std::atomic<int> *pRefCnt_ = nullptr;
  T *pObj_ = nullptr;

  void destroy() {
    if (pRefCnt_ && *pRefCnt_-- == 0) {
      delete std::exchange(pRefCnt_, nullptr);
      delete std::exchange(pObj_, nullptr);
    }
  }

  void copy(SharedPtr const &other) {
    pRefCnt_ = other.pRefCnt_;
    pObj_ = other.pObj_;
    if (pRefCnt_) {
      ++*pRefCnt_;
    }
  }

  void move(SharedPtr &&other) {
    pRefCnt_ = std::exchange(other.pRefCnt_, nullptr);
    pObj_ = std::exchange(other.pObj_, nullptr);
  }

public:
  SharedPtr() = default;

  explicit SharedPtr(T *p) : pRefCnt_(new std::atomic<int>(0)), pObj_(p) {}

  SharedPtr(SharedPtr const &rhs) noexcept { copy(rhs); }

  SharedPtr(SharedPtr &&rhs) noexcept { move(std::move(rhs)); }

  SharedPtr &operator=(SharedPtr const &rhs) noexcept {
    if (this != &rhs) {
      destroy();
      copy(rhs);
    }
    return *this;
  }

  SharedPtr &operator=(SharedPtr &&rhs) noexcept {
    if (this != &rhs) {
      destroy();
      move(std::move(rhs));
    }
    return *this;
  }

  ~SharedPtr() { destroy(); }

  T *operator*() const { return pObj_; }
  T &operator->() const { return *pObj_; }
  explicit operator bool() const { return pObj_ != nullptr; }
};
```

Comment: the `int` is atomic, but not the pointer. Do you mean `std::atomic<int*>` ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I am trying to make the smart pointer structure thread safe. Not the reference to the ref count

Comment: The destructor is ok, but you ask about the whole implementation eg copying, assigning, moving etc, without showing the code, so how can we tell ?

Comment: Two notes: 1: When you add a move constructor, you probably move the counter pointer. Make sure to check it against nullptr in the destructor. May also be necessary for default (nullptr) constructors. 2. Your ```fetch_sub``` enforces sequential consistency. That is more than required. ```memory_order::acq_rel``` should be enough

Comment: @RichardCritten I have add more clarification. Please reconsider the question. Thank you.

Comment: The counter increment can be ```fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed)``` for improved performance. Otherwise it looks okay

Comment: @RichardCritten How would that be possible without that thread accessing a dangling pointer? I think that is fine. Of course the ```shared_ptr``` itself is not threadsafe, but neither is ```std::shared_ptr```

Comment: have changed my mind - was still thinking ....

Comment: One more note: Shouldn't the atomic be initalized to 1 instead of 0? A constructed object starts with one reference, and your destructor checks against 0.

Comment: @Homer512 note that destructor uses *post decrement*, so it is balanced out.

Comment: This may be better suited to codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt the question is "Does this implement thread safety the way the standard requires". It is not "What are some possible improvements?". Ergo I am asking for an answer about the concept itself, not the quality of this implementation.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt thank you for your attention :) Though I am aware of the existence of the other website.